# Pass data between activities Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android-intent, xamarin.android

I am trying to pass data between two activities using `Intents`, but at the moment when I try to get the data from the previous activity it just gives me a value of 0 when I print it on the view.

I've searched for ages, but everything I find doesn't exist or is deprecated :(

FirstActivity:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;

namespace PayrollCalculator
{
    [Activity(Label = "FirstActivity")]
    public class FirstActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.first_activity_layout);
            //payroll month
            Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.monthSpinner);
            var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.month_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
            adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
            spinner.Adapter = adapter;
            int monthsRemaining = 11;
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "January")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 11;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Febuary")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 10;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "March")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 9;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "April")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 8;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "May")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 7;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "June")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 6;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "July")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 5;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "August")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 4;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "September")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 3;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "October")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 2;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "November")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 1;
            }
            if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "December")
            {
                monthsRemaining = 0;
            }

            //marital status
            Spinner spinner2 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.statusSpinner);
            var adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.status_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
            adapter2.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
            spinner2.Adapter = adapter2;

            //disabled
            RadioButton disabledTrue = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioDisabledTrue);
            RadioButton disabledFalse = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioDisabledFalse);

            //spouse disabled
            EditText errorView = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.erroreditview);
            RadioButton spouseDisabledTrue = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioSpouseDisabledTrue);
            RadioButton spouseDisabledFalse = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioSpouseDisabledFalse);
            spouseDisabledTrue.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                disabledSpouseCan();
            };
            spouseDisabledFalse.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                disabledSpouseCan();
            };

            //kidsunder18 or in education 2000
            EditText kidsU18 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.u18kids);
            int.TryParse(kidsU18.Text, out int _kidsU18);

            //over 18 HE 8000
            EditText over18inHE = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.over18inHE);
            int.TryParse(over18inHE.Text, out int _over18inHE);

            //disabled 6000
            EditText disabledChildren = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.disabledChildren);
            int.TryParse(disabledChildren.Text, out int _disabledChildren);

            //disabled HE 14000
            EditText disabledChildreninHE = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.disabledChildreninHE);
            int.TryParse(disabledChildreninHE.Text, out int _disabledChildreninHE);

            double disabledDeduction = 0.00;
            if (disabledTrue.Checked == true)
            {
                disabledDeduction = 6000.00;
            }
            double disabledSpouseDeduction = 0.00;
            if (spouseDisabledTrue.Checked == true)
            {
                disabledSpouseDeduction = 3500.00;
            }
            double spouseNoIncomeDeduction = 0.00;
            if (spinner2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Married and spouse not working")
            {
                spouseNoIncomeDeduction = 4000.00;
            }
            double totalFamilyDeductions = (_kidsU18 * 2000) + (_over18inHE * 8000) + (_disabledChildren * 6000) + (_disabledChildreninHE * 14000) + disabledDeduction + disabledSpouseDeduction + spouseNoIncomeDeduction;
            Button _firstContinue = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.continuePayroll1);

            _firstContinue.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (disabledSpouseCan() == false)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(this, "Check the error above", ToastLength.Short);
                    toast.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    PlayButton_Click(sender, e);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
                    intent.PutExtra("totalFamilyDeductions", totalFamilyDeductions);
                    intent.PutExtra("monthsRemaining", monthsRemaining);
                    StartActivity(intent);
                }
            };

            void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MediaPlayer _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Drawable.buttonclick);
                _player.Start();
            }
            bool disabledSpouseCan()
            {
                if ((spinner2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Single" | spinner2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Divorce/Widower/Widow") && (spouseDisabledTrue.Checked == true))
                {
                    errorView.Error = "You don't have a spouse";
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    errorView.Error = null;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Widget;

namespace PayrollCalculator
{
    [Activity(Label = "SecondActivity")]
    public class SecondActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.second_activity_layout);

            //currentmonthremu
            EditText currentMonthRemuneration_ = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.currentMonthRemuneration);
            currentMonthRemuneration_.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(12, 2) });
            double _currentMonthRemuneration = 0.00;
            currentMonthRemuneration_.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                double.TryParse(currentMonthRemuneration_.Text, out _currentMonthRemuneration);
            };
            //EPF
            EditText EPFContribution_ = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.EPFContribution);
            EPFContribution_.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(12, 2) });
            double _EPFContribution = 0.00;
            EPFContribution_.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                double.TryParse(EPFContribution_.Text, out _EPFContribution);
                Validate(_EPFContribution, 4000, EPFContribution_);
            };
            //BIK
            EditText BIK_ = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.BIK);
            BIK_.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(12, 2) });
            double _BIK = 0.00;
            BIK_.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                double.TryParse(BIK_.Text, out _BIK);
            };
            //VOLA
            EditText VOLA_ = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.VOLA);
            VOLA_.SetFilters(new IInputFilter[] { new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(12, 2) });
            double _VOLA = 0.00;
            VOLA_.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                double.TryParse(VOLA_.Text, out _VOLA);
            };
            double _EPFCombined =+ _EPFContribution;
            //this is where I try to get the data from the previous activity to display on my layout
            double _totalFamilyDeductions = Intent.GetDoubleExtra("totalFamilyDeductions", 0.00);
            TextView textView111 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView111);
            textView111.Text = "" + _totalFamilyDeductions;
            Button _secondContinue = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.continuePayroll2);
            _secondContinue.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (Validate(_EPFContribution, 4000, EPFContribution_) == false)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(this, "Please make sure EPF is below RM4000", ToastLength.Short);
                    toast.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    int _monthsRemaining = Intent.GetIntExtra("monthsRemaining", 11);
                    PlayButton_Click(sender, e);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ThirdActivity));
                    intent.PutExtra("currentMonthRemuneration", _currentMonthRemuneration);
                    intent.PutExtra("EPFContribution", _EPFContribution);
                    intent.PutExtra("BIK", _BIK);
                    intent.PutExtra("VOLA", _VOLA);
                    intent.PutExtra("EPFCombined", _EPFCombined);

                    intent.PutExtra("totalFamilyDeductions", _totalFamilyDeductions);
                    intent.PutExtra("monthsRemaining", _monthsRemaining);
                    StartActivity(intent);
                }
            };

            void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MediaPlayer _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Drawable.buttonclick);
                _player.Start();
            }
        }
        bool Validate(double name, double value, EditText editText)
        {
            if (name > value)
            {
                editText.Error = "Cannot be greater than " + value;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
    {
        readonly string regexStr = string.Empty;

        public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero, int digitsAfterZero)
        {
            regexStr = "^[0-9]{0," + digitsBeforeZero + "}([.][0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?$";
        }

        public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(regexStr);

            if (regex.IsMatch(dest.ToString()) || dest.ToString().Equals(""))
            {
                if (dest.ToString().Length < 12 && source.ToString() != ".")
                {
                    return new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
                }
                else if (source.ToString() == ".")
                {
                    return new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
                }
                else if (dest.ToString().Length >= 13 && dest.ToString().Length <= 20)
                {
                    return new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);

                }
            }

            return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to display `_totalFamilyDeductions` on the view It just displays 0.

Any help Appreciated!

Comment: Try to make a break point at   `double totalFamilyDeductions = (_kidsU18 * 2000) + (_over18inHE * 8000) + (_disabledChildren * 6000) + (_disabledChildreninHE * 14000) + disabledDeduction + disabledSpouseDeduction + spouseNoIncomeDeduction;`,make sure you get the right values.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I added a breakpoint at that point but the code stops before I can even type the values of all the fields

Comment: I think I know that you get the values of `totalFamilyDeductions`  before you deal with them, but at this time they are all default values of 0, and you need to obtain them after you deal with them.For example,you should do in the TextChanged event.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I'm not sure how I would do that. if you have an answer to my question I would love to see it, but I can just get each of the separate deductions and add them up in the second activity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code above I assume that it should be:

```
private int _kidsU18;
private int _over18inHE;
private int _disabledChildren;
private int _disabledChildreninHE;
double disabledDeduction = 0.00;
double disabledSpouseDeduction = 0.00;
double spouseNoIncomeDeduction = 0.00;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.first_activity_layout);
        //payroll month
        Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.monthSpinner);
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.month_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner.Adapter = adapter;
        int monthsRemaining = 11;
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "January")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 11;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Febuary")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 10;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "March")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 9;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "April")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 8;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "May")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 7;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "June")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 6;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "July")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 5;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "August")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 4;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "September")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 3;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "October")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 2;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "November")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 1;
        }
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.ToString() == "December")
        {
            monthsRemaining = 0;
        }

        //marital status
        Spinner spinner2 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.statusSpinner);
        var adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.status_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
        adapter2.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner2.Adapter = adapter2;
        spinner2.ItemSelected += Spinner2_ItemSelected;

        //disabled
        RadioButton disabledTrue = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioDisabledTrue);
        disabledTrue.CheckedChange += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
        RadioButton disabledFalse = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioDisabledFalse);

        //spouse disabled
        EditText errorView = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.erroreditview);
        RadioButton spouseDisabledTrue = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioSpouseDisabledTrue);
        spouseDisabledTrue.CheckedChange += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
        RadioButton spouseDisabledFalse = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioSpouseDisabledFalse);
        spouseDisabledTrue.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {

            disabledSpouseCan();
        };
        spouseDisabledFalse.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            disabledSpouseCan();
        };

        //kidsunder18 or in education 2000
        EditText kidsU18 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.u18kids);
        kidsU18.TextChanged += EditText_TextChanged;

        //over 18 HE 8000
        EditText over18inHE = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.over18inHE);
        over18inHE.TextChanged += EditText_TextChanged;

        //disabled 6000
        EditText disabledChildren = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.disabledChildren);
        disabledChildren.TextChanged += EditText_TextChanged;

        //disabled HE 14000
        EditText disabledChildreninHE = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.disabledChildreninHE);
        disabledChildreninHE.TextChanged += EditText_TextChanged;


     
       
        Button _firstContinue = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.continuePayroll1);

        _firstContinue.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (disabledSpouseCan() == false)
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(this, "Check the error above", ToastLength.Short);
                toast.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                PlayButton_Click(sender, e);
                double totalFamilyDeductions = (_kidsU18 * 2000) + (_over18inHE * 8000) + (_disabledChildren * 6000) + (_disabledChildreninHE * 14000) + disabledDeduction + disabledSpouseDeduction + spouseNoIncomeDeduction;
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("totalFamilyDeductions", totalFamilyDeductions);
                intent.PutExtra("monthsRemaining", monthsRemaining);
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MediaPlayer _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Drawable.buttonclick);
            _player.Start();
        }
        bool disabledSpouseCan()
        {
            if ((spinner2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Single" | spinner2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Divorce/Widower/Widow") && (spouseDisabledTrue.Checked == true))
            {
                errorView.Error = "You don't have a spouse";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                errorView.Error = null;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

   private void Spinner2_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (((Spinner)sender).SelectedItem.ToString() == "Married and spouse not working")
        {
            spouseNoIncomeDeduction = 4000.00;
        }
    }
    private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
        if (e.IsChecked)
        {
            switch (radioButton.Id)
            {
                case Resource.Id.radioDisabledTrue:
                    disabledDeduction = 6000.00;
                    break;
           
                    break;
                case Resource.Id.radioSpouseDisabledTrue:
                    disabledSpouseDeduction = 3500.00;
                    break;
    
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
       
    }

    private void EditText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditText editText = sender as EditText;
        switch (editText.Id)
        {
            case Resource.Id.u18kids:
                _kidsU18 = int.Parse(editText.Text);
                break;
            case Resource.Id.over18inHE:
                _over18inHE = int.Parse(editText.Text);
                break;
            case Resource.Id.disabledChildren:
                _disabledChildren = int.Parse(editText.Text);
                break;
            case Resource.Id.disabledChildreninHE:
                _disabledChildreninHE = int.Parse(editText.Text);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Since I don't know your logic, you may need to adjust it yourself, but one thing to be clear is that if you change the data while typing or selecting, you need to change the data in the corresponding event.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks Leo:)

Comment: Actually, `EditText_TextChanged` function doesn't work it still doesn't add that amount to the next activity

Comment: @dan51 Try the update above int the `EditText_TextChanged` ,it's my mistake.